# Google Sheets IFS Text result based on multiple conditions FIX & SORT

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-docs, google-sheets-arrayformula, google

I'm very new to Google Sheets and I'm trying to make find the correct formula for a text result based on multiple conditions, here is my best crack at it:

`=arrayformula(IFS(B9:B="",V9:V="",and(I9:I>10%,M9:M>10%,U9:U>7),V9:V="STRONG BUY",and(I9:I>5%,M9:M>5%,U9:U>5),V9:V="BUY",and(I9:I>0%,M9:M>0%,U9:U>4),V9:V="HOLD",and(I9:I>-5%,M9:M>-5%,U9:U>2),V9:V="SELL",and(I9:I<-5%,M9:M<-5%,U9:U<=2),V9:V="STRONG SELL"))`

Does anyone why do I get the N/A result?
[image: Sheet]

Second of all, I'm trying to sort autosort the column U and i get the #REF error

This is my best crack at it, but It doesnt' work:

`=sort(A9:AE,20,false)`

[image: SORT]

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). Please ask only [one question per post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/222741). Consider sharing a publicly editable [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219) with _realistic-looking_ data, and showing your _hand-entered_ expected results there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `ifs()` formula is lacking a "default" branch. Try adding this to the list of conditions:

`, true, "(no condition matched)"`

Note that as written, the `ifs()` will only return one of two values: `true` or `false`. You cannot place a result in column `V` by specifying `V9:V="STRONG BUY"`. You may want to replace that comparison expression with simply `"STRONG BUY"`.

Comment: Thanks! This worked